# Using default and non default constructors in my application

Tags: java, constructor

I'm new to java and have a question about default and non default constructors. My professor wants us to use the default constructor for creation of object BOOK1, and then use the non default constructor for BOOK2, BOOK3 and BOOK4. I know a constructor is used with the creation of an object, but I guess I don't understand how i'm supposed to differentiate between the two. My class code is as follows, where I have both a default and non default constructor:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public final class BOOKItem {

    DecimalFormat intFormat = new DecimalFormat("000");
    DecimalFormat doubleFormat = new DecimalFormat("$#,##0.00");

    private int bookID;
    private int numberInStock;
    private double price;
    private double totalValueOfStock;
    private int code;
    private String genre = "";

    public BOOKItem() {
        bookID = 0;
        numberInStock = 0;
        price = 0;
        code = 0;
    }

    public BOOKItem(int newID, int newStock, double newPrice, int newCode) {

        setID(newID);
        setStock(newStock);
        setCode(newCode);
        setPrice(newPrice);


    }

    public void setStock (int newStock) {

        if (newStock >= 1 && newStock <=5000) {
            numberInStock = newStock;
        }
         else {
            numberInStock = 0;
        }
  }

public void setCode (int newCode) {

    if (newCode > 0) {
        code = newCode;
    }
}

public void setID (int newID) {
    if (newID >=11 && newID <= 111111) {
        bookID = newID;
    }
    else {
        bookID = 0;
    }
    }

public void setPrice (double newPrice) {
    if (newPrice >= 1.0 && newPrice <=150.0) {
        price = newPrice;
    }
    else {
        price = 0;
    }
}

public int getID () {

return bookID;
```

}

```
public int getNumberInStock () {
    return numberInStock;
}

public int getCode () {
    return code;
}

public double getPrice () {
    return price;
}

public double calcTotalValue () {
    totalValueOfStock = numberInStock * price;
    return totalValueOfStock;
}

public double getTotalValue () {
    return totalValueOfStock;
}

   public void display() {
       switch (code)
    {   
       case 1:               
         genre = "Romance";
           break;
       case 2: 
         genre = "Adventure";
           break;
       case 3:
         genre = "Sci-Fi";
           break;
       case 4:
         genre = "Mystery";
           break;
    }               
   System.out.println("Display:");
   System.out.println("Book ID: " + bookID + " NumInStock: " + numberInStock + " Code: " + genre + " Price: " + 
                      price + " TotalStockValue: " + calcTotalValue());
   }



}
```

Here is my application that uses the constructors(sorry about the break in the class code, i dunno why its doing that):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project7 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int bookID;
    int numberInStock;
    double price;
    int code;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    BOOKItem BOOK1, BOOK2, BOOK3, BOOK4;
    BOOK1 = new BOOKItem();
    BOOK2 = new BOOKItem();
    BOOK3 = new BOOKItem();
    BOOK4 = new BOOKItem();

    System.out.println("Enter in a blank separated list: ID, number in stock, quality, price" + 
                       "- use a BAD ID(<11 or >111111)");

    bookID = keyboard.nextInt();
    numberInStock = keyboard.nextInt();
    code = keyboard.nextInt();
    price = keyboard.nextDouble();

    BOOK1.setID(bookID);
    BOOK1.setStock(numberInStock);
    BOOK1.setCode(code);
    BOOK1.setPrice(price);
    BOOK1.display();

    System.out.println("Enter in a blank separated list: ID, number in stock, quality, price" + 
                       "- use a BAD STOCK(>5000)");

    bookID = keyboard.nextInt();
    numberInStock = keyboard.nextInt();
    code = keyboard.nextInt();
    price = keyboard.nextDouble();

    BOOK2.setID(bookID);
    BOOK2.setStock(numberInStock);
    BOOK2.setCode(code);
    BOOK2.setPrice(price);
    BOOK2.display();

    System.out.println("Enter in a blank separated list: ID, number in stock, quality, price" + 
                       "- use a BAD PRICE(>150.0)");

    bookID = keyboard.nextInt();
    numberInStock = keyboard.nextInt();
    code = keyboard.nextInt();
    price = keyboard.nextDouble();

    BOOK3.setID(bookID);
    BOOK3.setStock(numberInStock);
    BOOK3.setCode(code);
    BOOK3.setPrice(price);
    BOOK3.display();

    System.out.println("Enter in a blank separated list: ID, number in stock, quality, price" + 
                       "- use ALL GOOD DATA");

    bookID = keyboard.nextInt();
    numberInStock = keyboard.nextInt();
    code = keyboard.nextInt();
    price = keyboard.nextDouble();

    BOOK4.setID(bookID);
    BOOK4.setStock(numberInStock);
    BOOK4.setCode(code);
    BOOK4.setPrice(price);
    BOOK4.display();






 }
}
```

Am I doing something incorrect with the creation of my objects? How do I use the non default constructor for BOOK2, BOOK3 and BOOK4? I created it, but perhaps i'm using it incorrectly. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
 BOOK1 = new BOOKItem();
```

You are calling the default constructor (Construction without having any arguments)

After taking user input you would call the Non Default Constructor

```
bookID = keyboard.nextInt();
numberInStock = keyboard.nextInt();
code = keyboard.nextInt();
price = keyboard.nextDouble();

BOOK2 = new BOOKItem(bookID, numberInStock, price, code);
```

Use the above code to use the Parameterized Constructor (Non Default constructor)

This is called constructor overloading.

So for the objects you want to assign default values you call the default constructor
For the object you have information available with variables you sent them in the constructor that you have defined with parameters, To assign that value

Comment: Thank you for your response. So instead of listing the creation of ALL my objects in a row at the top, I really only want to do the first one, take the user input, then create the rest of the objects as you explained above? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: As you said, you want Book1 to use 'Default Constructor' and book2 - book4 with non default, you will have to take User inputs 3 times for that and initialize the Object by passing those values one by one to each of them

Comment: thanks again. So when using the non default constructor, i'm guessing I create the object just BEFORE I take the user input related to that constructor. Is that correct?

Comment: No Just After the user Input, because the user would be giving the information about the parameters
    int bookID;
    int numberInStock;
    double price;
    int code;
With these parameters you will call the non default constructor, passing these values BOOK3 = new BOOKItem(bookID, numberInStock, price, code);